# How do you get the type of widget used by a Django form field?

Tags: django, forms

I've got a form factory that dynamically builds a form based on data coming back from the MailChimp API. I'm building a test case for each of the types of widgets that the form may use (select, radio, and checkbox). Right now I'm searching for a substring within the `str()` representation of the field, however, I assume there is a way to directly determine the type?

```
GroupsForm = groups_form_factory()
form = GroupsForm()
for field in form:
    self.assertIn('type="checkbox"', str(field), 
                  "Form field should be represented by a checkbox.")
    # this works, but, isn't there a way to check the field's widget type?
```

Comment: you can look at the type of field.widget. use isinstance() or type(). widget types are defined in widgets.py: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/widgets.py

Comment: I tried that, I get: `AttributeError: 'BoundField' object has no attribute 'widget'`

Comment: did you try field.field.widget?

Comment: Perfect. You should put this as an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to get the the type of the widget in your code use `type(field.field.widget)`

`BoundField` is defined in `django.forms`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from myapp.forms import RestaurantReviewForm
>>> f = RestaurantReviewForm()
>>> from django.forms.widgets import TextInput
>>> for field in f: print type(field.field.widget), isinstance(field.field.widget, TextInput)
... 
<class 'django.forms.widgets.TextInput'> True
<class 'django.forms.widgets.TextInput'> True
<class 'django.forms.widgets.TextInput'> True
<class 'django.forms.widgets.TextInput'> True
<class 'django.forms.widgets.TextInput'> True
<class 'django.forms.widgets.CheckboxInput'> False
<class 'django.forms.widgets.Select'> False
<class 'django.forms.widgets.Textarea'> False
<class 'captcha.fields.CaptchaTextInput'> False
```